# Extracting data from complex output text file using perl and placing into new text file

Tags: perl

The complete output text file is hundreds of lines long, with relevant nuclear cross sections and a plethora of other data that I do not need for this particular problem. I am trying to extract the columns of data under "BURNUP" and the first "K-INF" from the file I attached. I am trying to extract this data and place it into a separate file. I am a newbie, and have a similar perl script from a professor. I have tried to adapt it to the information I am looking for but the only result I am receiving are the 2 print statements. Any suggestions?

[image: Sample of text file I am trying to extract data from]

[image: Code]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question and include the actual code and some example data. We cannot copy your code from an image to run it, so we cannot help you. Please see [mcve] and [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: Note you might benefit from using `unpack` instead of `split` since it seems your data is fixed width, and the number of fields can vary, but the column positions of the data remains the same. See [`perldoc perlpacktut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html) for more examples

Comment: Are the columns in your data separated by tabs or spaces?

Comment: To back up what @simbabque said; I would like to help you, but I have no intention of retyping your input data or your code in order to try it out. Firstly, it would take too much effort and, secondly, there's too much chance that I'd make an error in the transcription. If you still want help, please post text versions of your images. (I have no idea why anyone would think that images of text are useful, but it's a common occurrence, so I'm obviously missing something.)

Comment: @DaveCross I remember when I had to teach people how to take screenshots... what happened to that?

Comment: @shawn it looks like it's spaces, for a column-based format. Clearly a human-readable format, not meant for machine-readability as there are no record type prefixes. What confuses me a bit is that it seems it can only ever contain 99 records because the first column is too small for three digits. See how it's right-aligned with the heading?